# Blazor (MudBlazor) MudNumericField keeps returning 0 when no input value

Tags: blazor

I have a .razor page Test.razor that I have added a custom razor component called HTMLTextBoxOrLabel.razor

I cannot get the EventCallback to return a blank value incase the user doesnt input a value (it will always return 0)

Problem:
When I add a value to the MudNumericField all is ok and the value from the MudNumericField is collected and I update the database, but when I clear the MudNumericField to an empty value then it will always return the value of "0" (zero). I don't want zero, if the user wants to not have a value then I want it to return blank (null).

Is this possible?

EDITED……. Or is there a better way to communicate between parent and child razor components instead of using EventCallBack?

Test.razor

```
<EditForm Model="@businessClass" 
          OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit" 
          OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit">
      <DataAnnotationsValidator />
      <ValidationSummary />
      <HTMLTextBoxOrLabel 
          MaxLength="5"
          @bind-BindToSmallInt=
             "@text_I_am_pushing_from_codebehind.order_by"
</EditForm>
    
    @code
    {
    private void OnValidSubmit(EditContext context)
    {
        bool IsValid = context.Validate();
    
        if (IsValid)
        {
           //   This is where I keep getting the value 0 instead of blank (null)
            
           if (this.businessClass.Update())
           {
           }
        }
    }
}
```

HTMLTextBoxOrLabel.razor

```
<MudNumericField @bind-Value="@BindToSmallInt" T="Int16?" MaxLength="@MaxLength" />

    @code
    {
        [Parameter] public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    
        private Int16 _BindToSmallInt;
    
    
        [Parameter] public EventCallback<Int16> BindToSmallIntChanged { get; set; }
    
        [Parameter]
        public System.Nullable<Int16> BindToSmallInt
        {
            get => _BindToSmallInt;
            set
            {
                if (_BindToSmallInt == value) return;
    
                BindToSmallIntChanged.InvokeAsync(value.Value);
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: This requires a [mre]. Without `@text_I_am_pushing_from_codebehind.order_by`

Comment: And first try to reproduce this without MudBlazor.

Comment: @text_I_am_pushing_from_codebehind.order_by is a System.Nullable<Int16> data type in c#